# C# delegate or Func for 'all methods'?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, generics, anonymous-function

i've read something about Func's and delegates and that they can help you to pass a method as a parameter.
Now i have a cachingservice, and it has this declaration:

```
public static void AddToCache<T>(T model, double millisecs, string cacheId) where T : class
public static T GetFromCache<T>(string cacheId) where T : class
```

So in a place where i want to cache some data, i check if it exists in the cache (with GetFromCache) and if not, get the data from somewhere, and the add it to the cache (with AddToCache)

Now i want to extend the AddToCache method with a parameter, which is the class+method to call to get the data
Then the declaration would be like this

```
public static void AddToCache<T>(T model, double millisecs, string cacheId, Func/Delegate methode) where T : class
```

Then this method could check wether the cache has data or not, and if not, get the data itself via the method it got provided.

Then in the calling code i could say:

```
AddToCache<Person>(p, 10000, "Person", new PersonService().GetPersonById(1));
AddToCache<Advert>(a, 100000, "Advert", new AdvertService().GetAdverts(3));
```

What i want to achieve is that the 'if cache is empty get data and add to cache' logic is placed on only one place.

I hope this makes sense :)

Oh, by the way, the question is: is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
public static void AddToCache<T>(T model, double millisecs, string cacheId, Func<T> getValueFunction ) where T : class
{
  // if miss:
  var person = getValueFunction.Invoke();
}
```

The call would look like:

```
AddToCache( p , 1, "Person", () => new PersonService().GetPersonById(1) );
```

Answer (score 7):

You probably want:

```
public static void AddToCache<T>(T model, double millisecs, string cacheId, 
   Func<T> methode) where T : class;
```

Usage:

```
AddToCache<Person>(p, 10000, "Person", 
       () => new PersonService().GetPersonById(1));
```

Comment: The answer to the question title is that the `Delegate` class represents any func or delegate, but yes, this is probably what they want. +1

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read this blog post: [Get Your Func On](http://codebetter.com/blogs/karlseguin/archive/2008/07/03/get-your-func-on.aspx) . It discusses the problem you are solving with the same approach.